# Splashscreen does not appear

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I'm using cordova 11 for a native cross-platform Android application and setting the opening screen, but it doesn't appear and the icon keeps appearing

If I create an .xml for specific screens it doesn't open, but if I add a single screen it locates

```
<!-- Landscape/Paisagem -->
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/hdpi_land.png" density="land-hdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/ldpi_land.png" density="land-ldpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/mdpi_land.png" density="land-mdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/xhdpi_land.png" density="land-xhdpi" />

<!-- Portrait/Retrato -->
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/hdpi_port.png" density="port-hdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/ldpi_port.png" density="port-ldpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/mdpi_port.png" density="port-mdpi" />
<splash src="www/res/screen/android/xhdpi_port.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splashscreen format has changed with the newer versions of cordova-android.

Check out this issue : https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/1441

More info here : https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2022/07/12/cordova-android-release-11.0.0.html

Long story short, you need a single image

```
 <preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/screens/android/icon-288.png" />
```

You can also set a bg color

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#222" />
```